# select all books from one category except books which belong to other category

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: `books`, `book_categories`, `categories`.

`book_categories` table "joins" `books` and `categories`. It contains columns: `id`,`book_id`,`category_id`.

So one Book may belong to many categories and one Categorie may have many books.

I need query which retrieves all books from `given_category` except books which belongs to `given_set_of_categories`. So for example I want all books from category A but only if they don't belong also to category B or C. I need also sort (order) the result by Book.inserted column.

I know how to get all books from `given_category` with 2 joins but can't figure out how to exclude some books from other categories in result. I cant filter books in PHP because I am paginating the search result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where
  category_id = <given category>
  and books.book_id not in
(
 select book_id from book_categories
  where category_id in (<given set of cat>)
)
order by books.inserted
```

Comment: Works good but with number of elements in given_set > 1 it works VERY SLOW - like 15 seconds pn query... For now I have to exclude just 1 category and it work fine

Answer (score 0):

So, if you mean it is in one category but not in any other:

```
AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM books b JOIN book_categories bc ON b.id = bc.book_id JOIN categories c ON bc.category_id = c.id AND c.id = 'A')
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM books b JOIN book_categories bc ON b.id = bc.book_id JOIN categories c ON bc.category_id = c.id AND c.id != 'A')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this can be achieved through counting provided that book_categories entries are **unique**, thus the **combination book_id & category_id** are **not repeating**. Instead of trying directly to exclude records, we select from the combined set of categories [,] and then we'll count book_id entries that belong to the  :

```
COUNT(IF(category_id = <given_category>, 1, NULL)) as cnt_exists
```

and after ensuring that it contains the required category, we count the total to see if it belongs to any other category as well:

```
COUNT(*) AS cnt_total


SELECT * FROM books b JOIN (
  SELECT book_id, 
         COUNT(IF(category_id = <given_category>, 1, NULL)) as cnt_exists, 
         COUNT(*) AS cnt_total FROM book_categories WHERE
         category_id IN(<given_category>, <given_set_of_categories>)
) bc ON b.id = bc.book_id AND 
        cnt_exists = 1 AND cnt_total = 1 ORDER BY b.inserted
```